# When are sub-$\sigma$-algebras 'orthogonally complementable' in $L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces

For a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{G}\subseteq \mathscr{F}$, we have the orthogonal $L^2$-decomposition

\begin{equation}
L^2(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P}) \,=\, M \oplus M^{\bot} \qquad\text{for}\quad M:=L^2(\Omega, \mathscr{G}, \mathbb{P}).
\end{equation}

Are there conditions on $\mathscr{G}$ to guarantee that $M^{\bot}= L^2(\Omega, \mathscr{G}_{\bot}, \mathbb{P})$ for some sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{G}_{\bot} \subseteq \mathscr{F}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No complement (even non-orthogonal) of that $L^2$ space can be the $L^2$-space of another sub-$\sigma$-algebra for a finite measure (even a different one, as long as the underlying measured space is the same) due to constant functions being shared by both of them.

Comment: Thanks, @Bruno B. Could $M^\bot$ still be isomorphic to a suitable quotient of an $L^2$-space?

Comment: @fsp-b I have no idea, sorry.